# Need to show discounted price of bundle in the cart page

Tags: magento-enterprise, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, bundled-product

I have a coupon code promo of 15 percent (shopping cart rule), when a user adds the product to the cart and applies the coupon code I need to show the original price and the discounted price of the bundle on the cart page

How to get the discounted price for a bundle on the cart page?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$_product->getFinalPrice();
```

to get the discounted product price.

If you also want to display the difference you can use

```
$_product->getPrice();
```

and subtract the result from getFinalPrice from it.

Comment: doesn't work for bundles